# Did Solomon write Ecclesiastes?

Tags: authorship, ecclesiastes, solomon, provenance

In addition to Proverbs there are other canonical texts that non-scholars tend to attribute to Solomon of more dubious origin.

What evidence is there that Ecclesiastes alleges to have been written by Solomon?

If so, is it credible? If so, what evidence is there?

See related: [Did Solomon write Song of Solomon?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/34184/did-solomon-write-song-of-solomon)

Comment: Related: [Do linguistic features of Ecclesiastes rule out Solomon as the author?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/18597/2672)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The evidence for Solomonic authorship of Ecclesiastes is circumstantial (and so weak) and traditional; it is therefore inconclusive but does not exclude that conclusion.

The circumstantial evidence consists of the following:

- The text itself claims to have been written by "the son of David, king in Jerusalem" (Eccl 1:1, 12).  However, this could mean any of the Davidic line but does not exclude Solomon
- The style is very similar to Solomon's in his Psalm 72 and Proverbs, allowing for the differences in subject matter and later maturity of style.
- The narcissistic profligacy and repentance plus salutary warnings to others is consistent with Solomon's (meagre) history that we have.
- Since ancient times Ecclesiastes has been attributed to Solomon.  The first (to my meagre) knowledge to question this was Martin Luther; and many since.

The question of precise authorship may never be finally settled.

Comment: The points are relevant but not well supported. Can you provide sources? Thanks.

Comment: See some Luther's oblique comments in "Table Talk" at https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/09018328.2014.926695